# unable to create mgmt network in openstack , configuring openstack for OSM

Tags: openstack, openstack-neutron

unable to create mgmt network on openstack.

Tried creating "mgmt" network on openstack (OCATA  version) as per the given instruction in the link 
(Replaced to ocata version command keywords)

[configure openstack for OSM](https://osm.etsi.org/wikipub/index.php/Openstack_configuration_(Release_ONE))

I got the following response, No much info about the error

```
stack@kanine-openstack:~/devstack/accrc/admin$ openstack network create --provider-network-type VLAN --provider-physical-network physnet_enp0s8 --provider-segment 7777 --share mgmt
Ignoring domain related config project_domain_id because identity API version is 2.0
Ignoring domain related config user_domain_id because identity API version is 2.0
Ignoring domain related config project_domain_id because identity API version is 2.0
Ignoring domain related config user_domain_id because identity API version is 2.0
Ignoring domain related config project_domain_id because identity API version is 2.0
Ignoring domain related config user_domain_id because identity API version is 2.0
Ignoring domain related config project_domain_id because identity API version is 2.0
Ignoring domain related config user_domain_id because identity API version is 2.0
Error while executing command: Bad Request
```

I installed ubuntu on virtual box, Please find the interface

```
~$ ifconfig
br-ex     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 26:f9:df:8b:bb:49
          inet addr:172.24.4.1  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: 2001:db8::2/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fe80::24f9:dfff:fe8b:bb49/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:22 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:79 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1
          RX bytes:972 (972.0 B)  TX bytes:10796 (10.7 KB)

enp0s3    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:76:8f:15
          inet addr:10.0.15.112  Bcast:10.0.15.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::5bf2:65ab:b422:817b/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:48615 errors:0 dropped:1 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:43919 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:6642829 (6.6 MB)  TX bytes:10149498 (10.1 MB)

enp0s8    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:f4:3d:0f
          inet addr:10.0.10.5  Bcast:10.0.10.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::2a7:9404:baf9:ea12/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:23780 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:64 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:2539893 (2.5 MB)  TX bytes:10510 (10.5 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:320077 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:320077 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1
          RX bytes:164795161 (164.7 MB)  TX bytes:164795161 (164.7 MB)

virbr0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:00:00:00:00:00
          inet addr:192.168.122.1  Bcast:192.168.122.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

Please help me on creating the mgmt network.

Answer (score 0):

This error messages causes from different API version at the keystone.
If your API version is 2? it's not correct, Domain feature is as of Version 3.

so you change your auth URL as follows

`export OS_AUTH_URL=http://YOUR_KEYSTONE_IP:5000/v3`

And neutron network is not appear as the Ethernet device.
You check the current network list as follow command,

`$ openstack network list`

And share type network is required Admin authorization.